# Multiple Continue Handlers in DB2 for i Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm working with DB2 for i on IBM i V7R2 TR3

I am trying to write a stored procedure which contains two `SELECT` statements.  The first of which I loop through with a cursor, the second is inside of that loop.  If a record is returned from the second (inner) `SELECT` then I need to break out of the loop otherwise continue.  I've seen examples with `Exception Handlers`, but when I tried to implement them I would get thrown out of the loop on the first iteration.  My assumption as to why `Exception Handlers` do not work for me is because I'm setting the `Exception Handler` at a global level and when the second (inner) `SELECT` returns zero results during the first iteration (It will mostly return zero rows), the Exception Handler is trigger and I break out of the stored procedure instead of just the loop.

How can I set multiple `Exception Handlers` in a single stored procedure for specific SQL statements?  I've read about Compound Statements in DB2, but can't figure out how to specify which statement the `Exception Handler` is for.

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_compoundstatement4nativesqlpl.html

I've tried some alternative methods to `Exception Handlers` which is what I currently have.  I'm not dead set on `Exception Handlers`, but It would be nice to know how to use multiple `Exception Handlers`.

Here is my stored procedure (with changed lib/tables) for reference if it helps:

```
DECLARE EOF1 INT DEFAULT 0 ; 
DECLARE EOF2 INT DEFAULT 0 ; 
DECLARE CURMATCH CHAR ( 20 ) DEFAULT '' ; 
DECLARE CURPREFIX CHAR ( 20 ) DEFAULT '' ; 
DECLARE PREFIXES CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT  TRIM ( PREFIX ) || '%' 
    FROM    MYLIB / PREFIXTABLE 
    ORDER BY    LENGTH ( TRIM ( PREFIXCOL ) ) DESC , TRIM ( PREFIXCOL ) DESC ; 



OPEN PREFIXES ; 
WHILE EOF1 = 0 DO 

    FETCH FROM PREFIXES INTO CURPREFIX ; 

    IF TRIM ( CURPREFIX ) = '' THEN 
        SET EOF1 = 1 ; 
    END IF ; 

    SELECT  DISTINCT BASEITEM , 
        SUBSTR ( BASEITEM , 
        ( LENGTH ( TRIM ( CURPREFIX ) ) + 1 ) , ( 20 - LENGTH ( TRIM ( CURPREFIX ) ) ) 
    ) INTO CURMATCH 
    FROM    MYLIB / ITEMTABLE 
    WHERE   BASEITEM = ITEM 
    AND CASE 
            WHEN BASEITEM LIKE '' || CURPREFIX || '' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END = 1 ;        

    IF ( TRIM ( CURMATCH ) <> '' ) THEN 
        SET BASEITEM = TRIM ( CURMATCH ) ; 
        SET EOF2 = 1 ; 
    END IF ; 
    IF EOF2 <> 0 THEN 
        SET EOF1 = 1 ; 
    END IF ; 

END WHILE ; 
CLOSE PREFIXES ; 

IF(EOF2 = 0) THEN 
    SET BASEITEM = 'NOT FOUND'; 
END IF;
```

The stored procedure is set up to accept 2 parameters as defined:

```
IN ITEM CHAR(20) CCSID 37 DEFAULT  ''  , 
INOUT BASEITEM CHAR(20) DEFAULT  ''
```

I forgot to mention the above code seems to create an infinite loop.  When I call the procedure it just keeps running and doesn't stop.  I let it run as long as 10 minutes before killing it, and I don't think it would take that long given the number of records in these tables.

Comment: I see you have your answer...but just wanted to say that SQL isn't RPG.  You should be thinking set operations, not row by row using a cursor.  My motto (for those new to SQL) if you're using a cursor you're doing something wrong.  Yes, sometimes you have to use a cursor, but it's too easy for an RPG (or other procedural) programmer to use a cursor when it's not needed.  I suggest posting a new question with your code, the input and expected output along with samples of the tables and see if someone can show you the set based solution.

Comment: I'm with Charles - you can likely do this (and _faster_) in one statement.  Oh, you have a minor SQL injection vulnerability, since you're concatenating strings for searching.  Not terribly exploitable since they only get 20 characters, but you should still be using parameter markers.

Comment: I've changed the Stored Procedure up quite a bit while taking you suggestions into consideration.  Either way, I've posted a new question concerning the elimination of the use of a cursor as you suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661872/db2-400-alternative-to-opening-a-cursor

Comment: select * from itemtable where baseitem = initem join prefixes on substring(of something or other). = prefix   Good Luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signal (exception) handlers are local to blocks where they are declared. The procedure body is the outermost block, but you can define nested blocks. Since you didn't post your code (the one with the signal handler) I can't tell you exactly how to modify it, but in general it would look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE yourproc
...
BEGIN
  DECLARE prefixes CURSOR FOR ...
  OPEN PREFIXES ; 
  WHILE EOF1 = 0 DO 
    FETCH FROM PREFIXES INTO CURPREFIX ; 
    BEGIN -- inner block
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR ...
      ... -- do whatever
    END; -- inner block
  END WHILE ; 
  ...
END -- procedure
```

Basically, you wrap the statement(s) whose signals you wish to handle in a `BEGIN ... END` block and declare handler(s) inside that block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had to switch some other (mostly unrelated) stuff around to get it working in my particular use-case, but this is exactly what was needed.