# DB2/400 Alternative to Opening a Cursor

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm running DB2 for i, V7R2 TR3.

I was told opening a cursor provides a lot of overhead and should be avoided whenever possible.  From what I've read, using `EXECUTE INTO var1 USING var2` is an alternative, but I can't get it working.  I am getting a [SQL0104 error](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzala/rzalaml.htm%23messages__SQL0104?lang=en).

This is my Stored Procedure:

```
BEGIN 
DECLARE STMT1 VARCHAR ( 500 ) ;     

SET STMT1 =     'SELECT SUBSTR (''' || TRIM(ITEM) || ''' , ( LENGTH ( TRIM ( PREFIX ) ) + 1 ) , ( 20 - LENGTH ( TRIM ( PREFIX ) ) ) ) ' ||
                'FROM   MYLIB.MYTABLE ' ||
                'WHERE  PREFIX = SUBSTR(''' || TRIM(ITEM) || ''', 0,LENGTH ( TRIM ( PREFIX ) ) + 1 ) ' ||
                'AND    SEQ1 = ' || TYPE || ' ' ||
                'ORDER BY   LENGTH ( TRIM ( PREFIX) ) DESC , TRIM (PREFIX) DESC ' ||
                'FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY ';

PREPARE S1 FROM STMT1; 
EXECUTE S1 INTO BASEITEM;

--OPEN C1 ; 
--  FETCH C1 INTO BASEITEM ; 
--CLOSE C1 ; 

IF(TRIM(BASEITEM) = '') THEN
    SET BASEITEM = ITEM;
END IF;
END  ;
```

It has three variables defined as such:

```
IN ITEM CHAR(20) CCSID 37 DEFAULT  ''  , 
IN TYPE INT DEFAULT  1  , 
INOUT BASEITEM CHAR(20) DEFAULT  ''
```

When I have `EXECUTE INTO...` this will not compile, if I use `EXECUTE USING...` it will compile but `BASEITEM` ends up being blank and the `IF` statements resolves as true.

I've tried following the the [EXECUTE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzhexeqt.htm?lang=en) documentation and apparently the `INTO` can only work for `CALL` or `VALUES INTO` statements.  So I then tried to follow the [VALUES INTO](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzvalinto.htm?lang=en) documentation, but can't figure out how to use a query with it.

Note*: I'd like to eventually change the concatenated variables to use parameter markers, but I was going to worry about that next.

I figured I should post the table being used:
**MYLIB.MYTABLE**

```
Column |Prefix|SEQ1|SEQ2|
Row 1  |aaa   |   1|   3|
Row 2  |aab   |   1|   3|
Row 3  |aabd  |   2|   4|
```

I'm essentially passing in a string and then removing the longest prefix from the string.  Then I returned the new string.  `SEQ1` is just the type of prefix (either 1 or 2), SEQ2 is the length of the prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXECUTE` can only be used for DML statements, not for queries, so there is really no alternative to declaring a dynamic cursor. Having said that, there is no "overhead in opening a cursor", no more than in executing a query in any other manner, because for any query a cursor will still be created and opened implicitly, if not explicitly.

Cursors are less efficient than set-based operations, e.g. when, instead of doing something like `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT something FROM table2 WHERE...` you open a cursor over `table2` and insert rows into `table1` one by one in a loop. Inefficiency in such case arises from performing single row inserts (or updates) vs. multirow updates, not from the cursor itself, and that is completely different from stating that "opening a cursor provides a lot of overhead".

Since in your case you only fetch one record anyway, this loop vs. set argument does not apply.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clearing that up.  It basically comes down to the N + 1 problem and using certain methods to execute less queries to achieve a given goal.

Comment: Well stated.  But let me point out that there **is** additional overhead to dynamic SQL vs. static.  In addition to dynamic statements without parameters markers like the @d.lanza38 has being open to SQL injection attacks.  In this case, dynamic SQL isn't even needed.

Comment: @Charles the question was about the overhead of cursors in general (as compared to what, I don't know), not about static vs. dynamic statements.

Answer (score 5):

You're getting an error because `EXECUTE stmt INTO` doesn't work the way you think it does.

The real problem is that you're trying to use dynamic SQL when you don't need to be.  Use static instead.

```
BEGIN 

  SELECT SUBSTR (TRIM(ITEM), ( LENGTH ( TRIM ( PREFIX ) ) + 1 ) , ( 20 - LENGTH ( TRIM ( PREFIX ) ) ) )
    INTO BASEITEM
    FROM   MYLIB.MYTABLE 
   WHERE  PREFIX = SUBSTR(TRIM(ITEM), 0,LENGTH ( TRIM ( PREFIX ) ) + 1 )
          AND    SEQ1 = TYPE
   ORDER BY   LENGTH ( TRIM ( PREFIX) ) DESC , TRIM (PREFIX) DESC
   FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;

IF(TRIM(BASEITEM) = '') THEN
    SET BASEITEM = ITEM;
END IF;
END  ;
```

Comment: I wish I could mark more than one answer because this would be one of them as it was very helpful,@mustaccio just answered the actual question. Not using dynamic sql as you suggested improved the speed of this dramatically.  I originally started using dynamic SQL because I was trying to use a `LIKE` clause to compare the strings to the prefixes and had to concatenate with the % sign.  When I gave up on that I never realized converting it back would improve the performance.

Comment: @d.lanza38,  For future reference, you should be able to use `LIKE` in static statements.  About the only place you have to use dynamic is when the table name changes.  Dynamic may simplify complex `WHERE` or `ORDER BY`...but if you chose dynamic SQL over `CASE` statements in the `WHERE` or `ORDER BY`, make sure you use a parameter marker `'WHERE mycol = ?'` vs concatenating user input directly into the statement.